# Does akka send own messages to custom actor by own initiative?

Tags: akka, messaging, actor

I'm creating some actor which should wrap all the incoming messages with its own message and forward them further.
Unfortunately I don't have any common base class for user messages so I'm going to catch them with Object.class

Now I'm not sure if Akka can send its own messages to my Actor. I don't want to occasionally forward some system message which addressed to my wrapper actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka does internally send messages to your actors. These messages extend the internal [`SystemMessage`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.3/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/sysmsg/SystemMessage.scala#L187) trait. As the description in the source code states, system messages form their own queue in each actor's mailbox and are handled separately from other messages. We can trace the processing of these messages in [`Mailbox`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.3/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/Mailbox.scala#L260) and [`ActorCell`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.3/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala#L420).

When your forwarding actor receives a `SystemMessage`, that message is *not* wrapped and forwarded. Akka handles these messages internally, so your forwarding actor's behavior won't disrupt this system-level activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
class WrapAndForwardActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ => {
      // blocking
      // do whatever you want to do with the incoming message
      sender forward "WrappedMessage"
    }

    case "AnotherExample" => {
      // non blocking
      val sendTo = sender()

      // do whatever you want to do with the message
      // non blocking futures

      //when future is complete
      sendTo forward "WrappedMessage"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not clear what it's about ... 
My problem is: forwarding relevance - I want to forward the messages that was send by users only (custom messages) but not framework's messages. And I'm not sure does the framework can send something like this at all to user-defined actor. So, If yes - the simple "forward them all" is not appropriate strategy.